# Installing Module during OSD Task Sequence from NuGet not found

Tags: powershell, sccm, mdt, dsc

I have an OSD task sequence which one of the steps runs a package containing the PowerShell DSC '.ps1' file and the '.MOF' configuration. Now during the task sequence it looks like it can't find the Modules I want to install on the NuGet provider and after logging in it's clear with the Get-PackageProvider command that it doesn't exist however the output of the SMTS log shows the output of NuGet as if it was installed.

[SMTS Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gp92.jpg)

I am using SCCM 1902 and am using the new PowerShell Script task sequence step and the script is running in Bypass mode and once I log in I can run the script manually without issue.

[PowerShell Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Yzd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue during TS where certain PowerShell cmdlets are not loaded till full OS. Unfortunately I can't see your TS log or Script via the links provided to confirm this, but I suspect you might be getting a false positive.

I fixed this by importing the module I needed before running the script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965375/get-wmiobject-failing-in-task-sequence